# Не получается правильно использовать Sprite.Create()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь использовать такой код:

```
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(size.x,size.y);
    tex.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
    tex.anisoLevel = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
        {
            tex.SetPixel(x,y,new Color(1,0,0,1));
        }
    }
    tex.Apply();
    var spr = Sprite.Create(tex,new Rect(0,0,size.x,size.y), new Vector2(0.5F,0.5F));
```

Но при записи "spr" в публичную переменную. И просмотре в инспекторе, создаётся с тем размером, но спрайт прозрачный

Comment: Вместо добавления [решено] в вопрос лучше ответить на него и пометить свой ответ как решение. В противном случае вопрос просто будет захламлять stack overflow.